# Setting up Anonymous User Access to Directory (SVN+SSH)

Tags: svn, ssh

I have an SVN repository currently setup through SSH. This works great for restricting access to the entire repository for read/write. However, I also want a single directory (i.e. `pub`) to be available to anonymous users for `checkout` only. Is there any easy way to do this given my current setup?